# Exception using a prepared statement with @BindIn annotation

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I'm using `org.skife.jdbi.v2.unstable.BindIn` in my prepared statements. It works as expected unless I try to concatenate the parameter in the query.

Below are 3 queries. The first 2 queries work as expected, but the third query gives this error:

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations

```
SELECT
     name  
FROM
     myTable WITH(NOLOCK)   
WHERE
    ID in ( <ids> )



declare @query VARCHAR(MAX)
select @query = '
  SELECT
     name
  FROM
       myTable WITH(NOLOCK)
  WHERE
       ID in (1, 2, 3)'
execute(@query)



declare @query VARCHAR(MAX)
select @query = '
SELECT
    name
FROM
    myTable WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE
    ID in (' + <ids> + ')'
execute(@query)
```

Comment: Why would you want to concatenate _parameters_ into a prepared statement? That defeats the purpose of using bind variables in the first place.

Comment: Because it's a part of a long, complex query which concatenates necessary declared variables.